# Crate - Records ingested in Crate but records not showing via select query

Tags: crate

I need a help for a Crate issue, I have a crate cluster of version 1.0.2. Last few days we observing strange issue related to "select query" query on Crate server. We found that via "select query" records are not showing for few specific dates though records properly ingested in Crate. We checked via JSON files present in all cluster.
Can someone give us some input how to resolve this?

**Following troubleshoot performed:**
a. Restart all Crate clusters.
b. Refresh the cluster all clusters.
c. Trying to delete the partition for the day in which Data not showing, but Crate not allowing us to Delete.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

CrateDB is eventual consistent. If you don't look up the newly inserted records via primary key you need to issue an `refresh` command: https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/general/dql/refresh.html

Comment: I already tried refresh command. But didn't see the impact. Still, "select query" not returning any result.

Comment: Here is the error observed after running query
REFRESH TABLE tabeName PARTITION (day='2018-04-28T00:00:00-0400');

Error:
SQLActionException[PartitionUnknownException: No partition for table 'tableName' with ident '04732d9g6cpjed1k60o30c1g' exists]
SQLActionException: NOT_FOUND 4046 PartitionUnknownException: No partition for table 'tableName' with ident '04732d9g6cpjed1k60o30c1g' exists
 at io.crate.analyze.TableAnalyzer.getIndexNames(TableAnalyzer.java:62)

Comment: does this occur with the latest version (2.3.7) as well?

Comment: Thanks for Reply, I don't have version 2.3.7. And to upgrade current version to that its required acceptance cycle which will take tame.

Comment: Can you please validate that the records were successfully ingested? The error indicates that the whole partitions does not exists, can you also please check the existence of that paritions? `select * from information_schema.table_partitions where table_name = 'tableName'` should give you a list of all existing partitions.